# numpe.zeros wrong 0 is being transformed

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a problem with switching numbers with the np.zeros command.

The code is supposed to let me click on one of the nine squares on the screen, and it should switch the zero in the list of zeros to a one, corresponding to the position of the square that I clicked. Instead, when i click randomly on the different squares, it usually outputs an x formation like this, though I find it to be rather inconsistent:

```
    [[1. 0. 1.]
     [0. 1. 0.]
     [1. 0. 1.]]
```

I've tried googling it, looked through some search results, couldn't find anything like this, and I've skimmed through some of the questions alreadt on StackOverflow, but I am not finding an answer.

Here is my code.

```
    import pygame
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    import math

    pygame.init()

    ROWS = 3
    COLS = 3

    def drop_piece(board, x, y, tun):
        turn = tun + 1
        board[x][y] = turn

    def isValidMove(board, x, y):
        return board[x, y] == 0

    def create_board():
        board = np.zeros((ROWS, COLS))
        return board

    def print_board(board):
        print(board)

    board = create_board()
    width = 999
    height = 999
    turn = 0
    displaySize = (width, height)
    gameOver = False
    print_board(board)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(displaySize)

    while not gameOver:

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            rawx = event.pos[0]
            rawy = event.pos[1]
            usex = int(math.floor(rawx / 333))
            usey = int(math.floor(rawy / 333))

            if isValidMove(board, usex, usey):
                >if turn == 0:
                    >print(usex,", ",usey)
                    drop_piece(board, usex, usey, turn)


            print_board(board)
            turn += 1
            turn = turn % 2
```

Comment: Why are you accessing `board[x, y]` in one place and `board[y][x]` in another? Which coordinate is supposed to be the x coordinate?

Comment: You're right, and I just changed it to be the same. It's supposed to be board[x][y]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code (it needed some adjustment) and it works perfectly fine for me. Code I used:

```
import pygame
import sys
import numpy as np
import math

pygame.init()

ROWS = 3
COLS = 3

def drop_piece(board, x, y, tun):
    turn = tun + 1
    board[y][x] = turn

def isValidMove(board, x, y):
    return board[x, y] == 0

def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((ROWS, COLS))
    return board

def print_board(board):
    print(board)

board = create_board()
width = 999
height = 999
turn = 0
displaySize = (width, height)
gameOver = False
print_board(board)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(displaySize)

while not gameOver:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            rawx = event.pos[0]
            rawy = event.pos[1]
            usex = int(math.floor(rawx / 333))
            usey = int(math.floor(rawy / 333))

            print(usex,", ",usey)
            drop_piece(board, usex, usey, turn)


            print_board(board)
            turn += 1
            turn = turn % 2
```

Example output:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
0 ,  0
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
1 ,  0
[[1. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
2 ,  0
[[1. 2. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
1 ,  0
```

Can anybody confirm or deny this?